# Rails 4 no longer redirects to user on create

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm adding client side geocoding to my users so I don't eat up a bunch of api calls on my server. I do this by adding hidden fields for longitude and latitude in my new users for, and jquery updates those hidden fields whenever the form changes.

For some reason, my browser is no longer doing anything when I click the submit button. The server says it redirected to user and all my assets there are rendered. But the browser just doesn't do anything. No errors, nothing. Once I refresh, I can see that I've been logged in under the new user. My controller tests all pass.

I was thinking it was a problem with my js, but when I commented out the code and put in the coordinates manually, the same thing happens.

Has this ever happened to anyone? Any ideas? Thanks.

**Edit:**

Here is the view:

```
    <%= form_for(@user, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">

    <div class="input-group", id="address-info">
        <%= f.text_field :street, placeholder: 'Street Address', class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.text_field :city, placeholder: "City", class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.select :state, us_states, {}, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <%= f.hidden_field :latitude, id: "lat" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :longitude, id: 'lng' %>

    <%= f.submit :Submit, class: 'btn btn-primary form-control' %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

and my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#address-info').change( function () {
    codeAddress()
  });
})

function codeAddress() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
var address = $('#user_street').val() + ", " + $('#user_city').val() + ", " + $('#user_state').val();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat()
        var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
        $('#lat').val(lat)
        $('#lng').val(lng)
    } else {
        console.log("error" + status);
    }
})
}
```

I removed some irrelevant code.

Comment: You'll need to post some code.  Especially that view and associated JS.

Comment: Why do you have `:Submit` instead of a simple button label like `'Submit'`?  Can you confirm your controller is not getting these Ajax requests at all?  I find [this article](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/) very helpful for debugging Rails Ajax.

Comment: OH I figured it out. REALLY DUMB. I left "remote: true" in there from when I was testing something out. Removing it fixed it. Thanks for your help anyway.